# Lost British Passport number

Tags: australia, uk-citizens, passports

I migrated to Australia in 1974 with my 5 month daughter on my British passport. This passport expired in 1984, was never renewed, and has been lost for many years.  For work reasons my daughter needs to provide the number of my passport. She has, in fact, lost her job even though she has her own British passport. Apparently someone in the human resource department where she was employed decided she is not eligible to work in Australia. I have searched everywhere I can think of but to no avail. Does anyone know where I might find this number???

Comment: You could try the [British High Commission in Canberra](https://www.gov.uk/government/world/organisations/british-high-commission-canberra/office/british-high-commission-canberra), or one of the British Consulates (in Brisbane, Melbourne, Perth and Sydney). Even if they can't help directly, they'd be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Why not make a [Freedom of Information request](https://www.gov.uk/make-a-freedom-of-information-request/organisations-you-can-ask-for-information) directly to the UK Passport Office? It appears it may be free (depends on what is asked), responses are received in as little as 20 days, and can be done electronically.

Comment: Your daughter never became an Australian citizen?

Comment: You might also contact Australian immigration as they should also have a record of the passport you entered with.

Comment: @PaulofOsawatomie The answer would be the same if the asker needed the number of a lost passport for travel reasons (e.g., applying for a new passport to travel), so I see no reason to close.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I have gladly withdrawn my close vote although I don't totally agree.

Answer (score 2):

This has come up on [Travel.SE before](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45398/101), and so I quote the relevant parts that apply:

> If you had pages of your passport certified by a solicitor or notary,
>   they would also have taken a photocopy of the portrait page.  Law
>   firms have a [varying retention framework](http://www.lawsociety.org.uk/support-services/help-for-solicitors/practice-advice-service/q-and-as/how-long-should-i-retain-my-closed-files-in-storage/) unlike companies, and
>   many like to preserve their archives for a long time.
>
> If these fail, and as a last resort, you can file a [Subject Access
>   Request](https://ico.org.uk/your-data-matters/your-right-of-access/) with the Home Office.  There is a fee for this and you
>   must clear hurdles imposed by the [Data Protection Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Protection_Act_1998).  A Subject
>   Access Request obliges the Home Office to give you their records about
>   you along with what they know about you...  *if they want to*.  The
>   SAR must be in writing.